# Fetch API cannot load localhost:(port&path). URL scheme "localhost" is not supported

Tags: c#, reactjs, fetch

I create react app that use API created with Spring Boot.

I would like to send a file to the server via the form in my react app (The server works good because I can upload file in Postman).

This is my form:

```
   <form onSubmit={e => uploadFile(e)} >
           <input type="file" name="img" onChange={changeHandler} />
           <button>Add!</button>
   </form>
```

`uploadFile` and `changeHandler` methods:

```
 const [selectedFile, setSelectedFile] = useState()

const uploadFile = () => {
        const formData = new FormData()
        formData.append('File', selectedFile)

        fetch(`localhost:8080/courses/1/comments/1/img`, {
            method: 'post',
            body: formData
        })
            .then(resp => resp.json())
            .then(data => console.log(data))
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }

    const changeHandler = (e) => {
        setSelectedFile(e.target.files[0])
    }
```

When I submit this form I get this:

```
Fetch API cannot load localhost:8080/courses/18/comments/1/img. URL scheme "localhost" is not supported.
```

How to solve this problem ?

Comment: You forgot the scheme (http or https)

Comment: Yes... Should I delete this questiuon ?

Comment: I think you should

Comment: I don't know, I had an error that got me here and I was just forgetting to connect with a prototcol, so this was a useful question for me.

Comment: @Monoxyd I also came here via searching for the same error, and it solved my problem. Why on earth would you want to delete such a question? What is the purpose of stackoverflow, if not for questions like this?

Comment: For me it was that I haven't updated the SignalR Message pack as it was version 5 which is deprecated now. Now, that it is version 8 everything works good.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You have to specify the URL as follows.

```
http://localhost:8080/courses/1/comments/1/img
```

Answer (score 10):

You might be forgot to specify the http protocol in the URL.

So, replace `localhost:8080/courses/1/comments/1/img` in the fetch method with `http://localhost:8080/courses/1/comments/1/img`

```
fetch(`http://localhost:8080/courses/1/comments/1/img`, {
    method: 'post',
    body: formData
})
```